# Download from FTP with anonymus id using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have the following code to download files from an FTP server, now this was used for a server with a set id and password.
I'm not able to set it with an anonymous id.
Could someone tell me how to do it?
When trying how it is I'm getting 'Variable not defined' for Username.

I'm a beginner when it comes to VB so please do not be harsh and try to explain step by step.

````
Sub Download_ftp_files()

'****************** Section 1 ******************
Dim fso, ofso, MySite
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'****************** Section 2 ******************
'This script is created to download files from FTP servers for CuteFTPPro window application.
'Create FTEConnection object
Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection")

'Connect FTP Server
'It will connect remote server host name, protocol, port, etc.
MySite.Host = "10.16.1.111"
MySite.Protocol = "FTPS_IMPLICIT"
MySite.Port = 21
MySite.Retries = 30
MySite.Delay = 30
MySite.MaxConnections = 1
MySite.TransferType = "AUTO"
MySite.DataChannel = "DEFAULT"
MySite.ClearCommandChannel = False
MySite.ClearDataConnection = False
MySite.AutoRename = "OFF"

'****************** Section 3 ******************
'Enter Username and Password –


UserName = "anonymus"
MySite.Login = UserName

UserPassword = "nul"
MySite.Password = UserPassword

MySite.SocksInfo = ""
MySite.ProxyInfo = ""

'Connecting to Remote Server
MySite.Connect


'****************** Section 4 ******************
'You can skip this section if you don’t want to delete old files.
'Delete data from Download Folder (C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'If you want to delete all files in the folder:
    Kill "C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\*.*"

    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '****************** Section 5 ******************
'It will create folder if it is not exist
If Len(Dir("C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir ("C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\")
End If


'****************** Section 6 ******************
'Downloading all files from ftp location to Download Folder (C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\)
'You can add multiple ftp location as below

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MySite.DownloadAsync "mes/reports/2021-03-18/", "C:\Source Folder\FTP Files\"
   


'****************** Section 7 ******************
'Pop-up message to show completion of downloading.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("All Files Downloaded")

End Sub ```
````

Comment: `Dim UserName As String`, `Dim UserPassword As String`. Best to declare all variables.

Comment: https://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp9/downloading_with_a_script.htm shows an anonymous transfer - note you have a typo "anonymus"

Answer (score 0):

Below a code, I used that works,

````
Sub Download_ftp_files_2()

'Get a reference to the TE COM object.
Dim MySite

Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection")

MySite.Protocol = "FTP"

MySite.Host = "xx.x.xx.xxx"

MySite.Login = "anonymous"

MySite.Password = "user@user.com"

MySite.UseProxy = "BOTH"

MySite.FileOverWriteMethod = "NUMERATE"

MySite.Connect


'Quit (1)

Kill "C:\Users\xxxxxerbinski\Desktop\FTP Files\*.*"
'The script will now check to see if the local folder c:\temp exists and will create it if necessary

If (Not (MySite.LocalExists("C:\Users\xxxxxrbinski\Desktop\FTP Files"))) Then

MySite.CreateLocalFolder "C:\Users\xxxxerbinski\Desktop\FTP Files"

End If

'Change TE's local working folder to to c:\

MySite.LocalFolder = "C:\Users\xxxerbinski\Desktop\FTP Files"

'Check for existence of remote folder FTP Files
Dim b As String

b = MySite.RemoteExists("mes/reports/2020-03-22/")


'Now download the index file to the local destination folder

MySite.Download "mes/reports/2021-03-22/mes_kpi_packing.csv"

'Complete. Show the status of this transfer.


MySite.Disconnect

MySite.Close

End Sub```
````